# How to read the file using line number - node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am working in `node.js`.

#### Requirement:

```
Note: Log - directoryName(Contains log files)
```

1. Have to listen to the `log directory` change. If any log files added to the log directory, I have to read the particular added log file.
2. If any content is appended to the existing file. Have to read that particular changes not entire file.

#### Note:

I am using [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) to watch the directory.

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
var watcher = chokidar.watch('../log', {ignored: /[\/\\]\./, persistent: true});

 watcher.on("add", function(path){
    new lazy(fs.createReadStream(path)).lines.forEach(function(line) {
        console.log(line.toString());
    });
 }).on("change", function(path){
    //Reading from first line
    new lazy(fs.createReadStream(path)).lines.forEach(function(line) {
        console.log(line.toString());
    });
 });
```

#### Problem

The above code is working based on the directory change and file addition. Problem is while reading the file. If some file changes i want to read only particular changes not from beginning.

Is there any node module to read only appended content in the file?

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [node-tail](https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail) or check out how it does it: https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail

First it will records the size of the file, using fs.statSync, and then on every change, it gets the new size. Then it starts reading the file from the previous recorded end(the size of the file) till the new size.

[fs.createReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_fs_createreadstream_path_options) supports `start` and `end` options for reading the file.